# Authorizing Salesforce Dev Org From VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

When I am trying to authorize my dev org in VSCode, I am getting the below error? Is anyone facing the same issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried going into my Chrome Browser Settings > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Third Party Cookies > See All Site Data and Permissions and clicked "Clear All Data". That worked for me.